# Is is possible to add a layer to a UITableView on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, calayer

I've been trying to add a simple layer to my UITableView and it seems that the layer is drawn over the tableview components. So, is possible to put a layer under the table components or the only way would be to put the tableview into a some kind of view?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If the layer is being drawn over your tableview, it sounds like adding the layer has worked.

Comment: Yeah, but the layer should be under the tableview components

Comment: Couldn't you make the tableview have a transparent background and put a view under the table?

Comment: Since the UITableViewController only contains a tableView as member, I don't really know how to put a view "under". If your solution works, I would be happy to use it. Seems good enough for what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After rereading the [help](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/backgroundView) I found exactly what I wanted:

```
UIView* simpleView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
tableVC.tableView.backgroundView = simpleView;
```

So simple...

Answer (score 0):

The UITableView *is* in a view.  A UITableViewController is a UIViewController and has a view property.  That view array has the tableview in it.  You should be able to add your simple subview below the tableView:

```
[tableVC.view insertSubview:simpleView belowSubview:tableVC.tableView];
```

If you wanted to add a CALayer that's different.  I wasn't sure if you were adding a CALayer or a UIView.

Comment: I found your reasoning quite interesting. But when I do: NSLog(@"View count: %d", [self.view.subviews count]); the output is 0. So that means the tableview is not inserted in the view. Also I'm on OS 4, but I don't think that change this fact. So, when adding a subview, it's automatically added to the front of the tableview.